# Стояло или состояло (оружие на вооружении)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Оружие **стояло** на вооружении или **состояло**?

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Чаще говорят *"**состояло** на вооружении".*

Comment: спасибо огромное